# NSDatepicker buttons in graphical style

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, nsdatepicker

Anybody knows if it's possible to modify the date picker three little grey buttons (in its upper left corner) behavior?

I want the date picker displays the current day when clicking in the middle button (the circle one).

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [NSDatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDatePicker_Class) contains an [NSDatePickerCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDatePickerCell_Class/) that handles most of the drawing and actions, the short answer is no, there's not an easy way to modify the behavior of the middle button.

However, I have discovered that option-clicking this button will jump to today. :-)